# Indented text after title

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

How can I achieve this

[image]

without specifying indent size? I found tips, how to indent all paragraph etc., but I think, thats not what I want. I need easy way, because I found it in many documents (title + description) and it looks like thats a some kind of `\paragraph{}`.

Comment: that just looks like a description environment with `\item[Subscriber]` but without a real example code it is hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @David Carlisle, it seems you're after a description environment, with the ‘title’ on a line of its own. You can obtain this very easily with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength\parindent{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline, listparindent=\parindent, parsep=0pt]
  \item[The First Item]This text describes the first item.
  \item[The Second Item]This text describes the second item.
        Contrary to the description of the first item, it is quite a bit longer.

        Additionally, it consists of multiple paragraphs, which causes problems
  with redefining the item command.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @David Carlisle: Oh! yes. I  adapted an old code and didn't even see the braces. Thank you for pointing it.